# register dependency css and js inside a plugin class

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, css, javascript

I have this code:

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_script' , array( $this, 'initBootstrap' ));
    add_action('wp_enqueue_style' , array( $this, 'initBootstrap' ));
    add_action('wp_register_script' , array( $this, 'initParallax' ));
    add_action('wp_register_style' , array( $this, 'initParallax' ));
    add_action('wp_register_script' , array( $this, 'initSwiper' ));
    add_action('wp_register_style' , array( $this, 'initSwiper' ));
    add_shortcode( 'bs-container', array( $this, 'contentWrapper') );
    add_shortcode('bs-col', array( $this, 'colWrapper') );
    add_shortcode('bs-parallax', array( $this, 'parallaxSeparator') );
    add_shortcode('bs-slider', array( $this, 'imgSlider') );
  }

  /*
  *
  */

  public function initBootstrap()
  {
    if( !wp_script_is( 'bootstrap.bundle.min.js' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' );
    }

    if( !wp_style_is( 'bootstrap.min.css' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/js/bootstrap.min.css' );
    }
  }

  /*
  *
  */

  public function initParallax()
  {
    if( !wp_script_is( 'universal-parallax.min.js' , '/js/universal-parallax.min.js' ) ){
      wp_register_script( 'parallax' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/js/universal-parallax.min.js' );
    }

    if( !wp_style_is( 'universal-parallax.min.css' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_register_style( 'parallax' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/css/universal-parallax.min.css' );
    }
  }

  /*
  *
  */

  public function initSwiper()
  {
    if( !wp_script_is( 'swiper.min.js' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_register_script( 'swiper' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/js/swiper.min.js' );
    }

    if( !wp_style_is( 'swiper.min.css' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_register_style( 'swiper' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/css/swiper.min.css' );
    }
  }
```

I want to register the dependency of a plugin but I'm unable to doing that, what's wrong with my code?
I've used the `add_action` inside the construct of my plugin class but the needed files are not loaded and the js and css are needed for the shortcodes I've registered. Can anyone suggest me a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the incorrect hook. The only hook is `wp_enqueue_scripts` (plural). You use `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_register_script()` etc. on that hook, but the hook is always the same.

So this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script' , array( $this, 'initBootstrap' ));
add_action('wp_enqueue_style' , array( $this, 'initBootstrap' ));
add_action('wp_register_script' , array( $this, 'initParallax' ));
add_action('wp_register_style' , array( $this, 'initParallax' ));
add_action('wp_register_script' , array( $this, 'initSwiper' ));
add_action('wp_register_style' , array( $this, 'initSwiper' ));
```

Needs to be:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , array( $this, 'initBootstrap' ));
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , array( $this, 'initBootstrap' ));
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , array( $this, 'initParallax' ));
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , array( $this, 'initParallax' ));
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , array( $this, 'initSwiper' ));
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , array( $this, 'initSwiper' ));
```

That's the reason it wasn't working, but you're also misusing `wp_script_is()`. It won't affect your code, since the result will always be false, but you need to pass the *handle* of the script, not the filename.

So this:

```
if( !wp_style_is( 'universal-parallax.min.css' , 'enqueued' ) ){
  wp_register_style( 'parallax' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/css/universal-parallax.min.css' );
}
```

Should be:

```
if( !wp_style_is( 'parallax', 'enqueued' ) ){
  wp_register_style( 'parallax' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/css/universal-parallax.min.css' );
}
```

However, you really don't need that condition at all. If the script is already enqueued, then nothing's going to happen, so there's no reason to check for it.

Comment: I'm checking it because usually I include bootstrap and other dependencies inside my custom themes. So I need to load the dependencies if they aren't already loaded. Thanks for the help. It will be best if I use only one class method to check and enqueue, and register styles/scripts is better than enqueue?

Comment: will this work for scripts and styles?